# LLVM storing Loop* in std::vector

Tags: c++, loops, llvm, llvm-c++-api

I've stumbled into something very peculiar - I'm writing an LLVM module Pass. I iterate over all functions of the module and then all loops of every non-declaration function and I store pointers to loops in a `std::vector`. Here's the source:

```
virtual bool runOnModule(Module& Mod){
  std::vector<Loop*> loops;
  // first gather all loop info
  for(Module::iterator f = Mod.begin(), fend = Mod.end(); f != fend; ++f){
    if (!(*f).isDeclaration()){
      LoopInfo& LI = getAnalysis<LoopInfo>(*f);
      for(LoopInfo::iterator l = LI.begin(), lend = LI.end(); l != lend; ++l){
          loops.push_back(*l);
      }
    }
  }
  for (auto& l: loops) errs () << *l << " ";
}
```

Now if I run this I get a runtime error - it can't print the loops, somehow I'm doing a null pointer dereference or sth. Any ideas?

Comment: How are you calling your pass?

Comment: @MarcoA. thorugh opt : opt -load passname ...

Comment: How do you attach a debugger to an llvm opt process?

Comment: you just rerun your `opt` with `gdb --args`, as usual. gdb should be able to intercept symbols loaded from a .so if you set your breakpoint in your code

Comment: baibo this looks like an interesting question that is not answered. It seems like you have resolved the issue. Would you add an answer so that it helps people in the future. My guess would be that since the reference LI goes out of scope once a loop iteration has ended, the loop pointers in the object that you have added are deleted by the LoopInfo's destructor, and hence the runtime error.

Comment: @Tushar just did :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure that the `LoopInfo` pass actually runs before your pass. Here is a complete example - stanalone from `opt`:

```
class AnalyzeLoops : public FunctionPass {
public:
  AnalyzeLoops()
      : FunctionPass(ID) {}

  void getAnalysisUsage(AnalysisUsage &AU) const {
    AU.addRequired<LoopInfo>();
  }

  virtual bool runOnFunction(Function &F) {
    LoopInfo &LI = getAnalysis<LoopInfo>();
    for (LoopInfo::iterator L = LI.begin(), LE = LI.end(); L != LE; ++L) {
      (*L)->dump();
    }
    return false;
  }

  static char ID;
};
```

In addition, when creating the passes, do:

```
  PassManager PM;
  PM.add(new LoopInfo());
  PM.add(new AnalyzeLoops());
  PM.run(*Mod);
```

I suspect that to make `opt` actually run `LoopInfo` before your pass, you should pass `-loops` too.

Also, note that I define `getAnalysisUsage` - this will make LLVM complain if `LoopInfo` didn't run before this pass, making the problem more obvious.

---

Note that `LoopInfo` is specifically a `FunctionPass`, and as an analysis it has to be used from another `FunctionPass`. The `LoopInfo` data structure doesn't really survive between different functions, and since it owns its data (those `Loop*` objects) they will be destroyed as well.

One thing you could do if you really need a `ModulePass` is just invoke `LoopInfo` manually and not as an analysis. When you iterate the functions in the module, for each function create a new `LoopInfo` object and use its `runOnFunction` method. Though even in this case, you have to make sure the `LoopInfo` that owns a given `Loop*` survives if you want to use the latter.

Comment: What you are saying is correct but, first of all, LoopInfo does run first - I have the getAnalysisUsage method defined. The problem is that I need to somehow store all loops from all functions in a Module and it cannot be done in the way I have shown. What you have provided is true but doesn't answer the question.

Comment: To add more - the pass is intentionally a Module pass, not a function pass, and I am getting run-time errors, not compile time errors.

Comment: @borisov: But `LoopInfo` is a function pass. It runs on the function before your pass runs. It should not be used on module pass level.

Comment: where would I have to add the PassManager stuff btw?

Comment: I solved my problem but your answer doesn't really cover the question now that I figured out what really was happening.

Answer (score 1):

First of all LoopInfo should run just once before the for loop.
Secondly LoopInfo::iterator just includes top level loops of the Function. in order to visit all loops you also need to iterate over subloops of every loop. it can be implemented either as recursive function or by WorkList, like this`

```
virtual bool runOnFunction(Function &F) {

  LoopInfo *loopinfo;
  loopinfo = &getAnalysis<LoopInfo>();
  std::vector<Loop*> allLoops;

  for (LoopInfo::iterator Li = loopinfo->begin(), Le = loopinfo->end();
       Li != Le; Li++) {
    Loop *L = *Li;
    allLoops.push_back(L);
    dfsOnLoops(L, loopinfo, allLoops);
  }
}

void dfsOnLoops(Loop *L, LoopInfo *loopinfo, std::vector<Loop*> LoopS) {
  std::vector<Loop *> subloops = L->getSubLoops();

  if (subloops.size()) {
    // recursive on subloops
    for (std::vector<Loop *>::iterator Li = subloops.begin();Li != subloops.end(); Li++){
        LoopS.push_back(*Li);
        dfsOnLoops(*Li, loopinfo, LoopS);
    }
  }
}
`
```

Comment: It doesn't matter - the pointers will be invalidated if you go out of scope. The question wasn't how to get them but why they are invalidated.

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers really helped but I managed to solve the problem myself. Basically, each llvm pass can define a releaseMemory() method, read more [here](http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html#the-releasememory-method). The LoopInfo class had that method implemented and thus the analysis information would be lost every time we get out of scope from the call to getAnalysis. I simply removed the releaseMemory() method in Loopinfo.h and the memory was no longer released. Note that this triggered a big change in the codebase and even opt had to be rebuilt so doing this in general is probably a bad idea and this would definitely not be easily accepted as a change to llvm (I speculate, not sure).

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to solve this is to explicitly create LoopInfo objects and save them. Here is the Code for LLVM 3.5

```
using LoopInfoType=llvm::LoopInfoBase<llvm::BasicBlock, llvm::Loop>;
std::vector<llvm::Loop*> loopVec;
std::vector<LoopInfoType*> loopInfoVec;

for(llvm::Module::iterator F = M.begin(); F!= M.end(); F++){
      //skip declrations
      if(F->isDeclaration()){
        continue;
      }


  //TODO that scope problem
  llvm::DominatorTree DT = llvm::DominatorTree();
  DT.recalculate(*F);
  LoopInfoType *loopInfo = new LoopInfoType();
  loopInfo->releaseMemory();
  loopInfo->Analyze(DT);
  loopInfoVec.push_back(loopInfo);

  for(llvm::LoopInfo::iterator lit = loopInfo->begin(); lit != loopInfo->end(); lit++){
    Loop * L = * lit;
    loopVec.push_back(L);
    //L->dump();
  }

}//for all functions

cin.get();

for(auto loop : loopVec){
  std::cout << "loop\n";
  loop->dump();
  for(llvm::Loop::block_iterator bit = loop->block_begin(); bit != loop->block_end(); bit++){
    llvm::BasicBlock * B = * bit;
    B->dump();
    std::cout << "\n\n";
  }
}
```